# Prove that the $p$-th power map is a homomorphism of $P$ ***INTO*** $Z(P)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $p$ is an odd prime and $P$ is a group of order $p^3$ then the $p$-th power map $\varphi:x\mapsto x^p$ is a homomorphism of $P$ ***INTO*** $Z(P)$. (Abstract Algebra: Dummit & Foote, Sec. 5.4, Ex. 9)

I've shown that $\varphi$ is indeed a homomorphism. I'm struggling to find why $\varphi(P)\le Z(P)$. Assume $P$ is non-abelian. Then $[P,P]=Z(P)$, which is of order $p$. Don't know if it helps. I've also used that fact that if $x,y\in G$ and both $x$ and $y$ commute with $[x,y]$, then for all positive integers $n$, $(xy)^n=x^ny^n[y,x]^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ in my proof that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.

I'm sure that the authors mean $\varphi(P)\le Z(P)$ instead of $\varphi(P)=Z(P)$ just by considering $P\cong\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p$. I've tried to found examples that can help me. For $P\cong\mathbb Z_9\rtimes\mathbb Z_3$, $\varphi(P)=Z(P)$ so the result isn't surprising. Just have no idea how to proceed. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the non-Abelian case, consider $H=P/Z(P)$ which has order $p^2$.
If $H$ has exponent $p$, the conclusion follows. The remaining case
has $H$ cyclic. Let its generator be $aZ(P)$.
Each element of $G$ will have the form $a^rc$ where $c\in Z(G)$.
But these all commute...

Comment: LOL, as soon as I saw $P/Z(P)$, I suddenly understood everything. Shame on me...